# Nestjs - How to get req.user from 2 different guards?

Tags: nestjs

In one of my controllers, I want to use 2 guards that do different checks.

those guards are extending AuthGuard.

How can I get req.user from 2 different guards without overriding one by another?

Example:

```
@UseGuards(MyAuthGuard, JwtOptionalAuthGuard)
@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {

...

@Get('profile')
    public async get        
@Req() req: any)
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that is possible. You'll probably have to create a third guard to do that. There's a strategy that selects one single guard and not a list of guards to process the request.

Comment: I don't really get the issues you're having... can you add more info and description? What did you try? What would you like to achieve? It is possible to have more than one guards simultaneously.

Comment: @noamsteiner so how can I get data from more than one guard simultaneously?

Comment: @Dave1987 Please describe the issues you're having. What did you try already and what does not work as you expect? 
You asked "How can I get `req.user` from 2 different guards", you get the user from the request not from the guard.